# Calling A Javascript Function Using 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry, please let me edit my question:

I have checkboxes that are defined:

```
echo "<td>"
    echo "<input type = \"checkbox\" name=\"name\" value=\"$name\">";
    echo "<input type = \"hidden\" name=\"user\" value=\"$user\">"; 
echo "</td>"
```

and a submit button:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Submit\" id=\"submit\" onclick=\"get_checked(form)\">";
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
        (function($){
            function get_checked(form){
                var formData = {};
                var match = false;

                var testname_checked = new Array();                
                $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                    testname_checked[i] = $(this).val();
                });
                if (confirm("You are requesting dumps for the following tests: \\n" + testname_checked.join('\\n') + "\\nPress \'Ok\' to confirm or \'Cancel\' to exit")){
                    $(form).find("input[name]").each(function (index, node){
                        formData[node.name] = node.value;
                        if (node.name == "user"){
                            var j = 0;
                            while (testname_checked[j]){
                                if (formData['testname'] == testname_checked[j]){
                                    //alert (formData['testname'] + formData['seed'] + formData['project']);
                                    $.post("http://ltipc197:4567",{testname: formData['testname'], seed: formData['seed'], project: formData['project'], changelist: formData['changelist'], suite: formData['suite'], user: formData['user'] } )
                                }
                                j = j + 1;
                            }
                        } 
                    }).get();
                }

            }
        })(jQuery);
```

As you can see, my function is wrapped inside the 'noConflict' function. However, when I press the submit button I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: get_checked is not defined. This only happens when I wrap the function inside the noConflict tag. I cannot remove this tag because I am using mootools in other parts of the script. I searched online and tried the following:

```
var noConflict = (function($){...}
```

Then I changed my button to be:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Submit\" id=\"submit\" onclick=\"noConflict.get_checked(form)\">"
```

But that didn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: `$(...).addEvents` *isn't* part of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1):

`$(...).addEvents` is a [MooTools feature](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Element/Element.Event#Element:addEvents). I suspect you are loading both libraries, which is a problem since both MooTools and jQuery claim the `$` global variable.

To bind jQuery to a different global and return `$` back to MooTools, use `$.noConflict`.

```
var jQ = $.noConflict();
jQ(':checkbox:checked').each(...);  // jQuery feature
$(...).addEvents();  // MooTools feature
```